Understanding それは別に映画の話であって
In this excerpt, I have trouble with それは別に映画の話であって part.
I am not sure whether それ refers to the situation described previously:「映画などを見ていると、知らぬ間に主人公に同一化してしまって、主人公が苦境に立つと、こちらも胸が苦しくなったり、知らぬ間に手を握りしめていて、汗ばんできたりする」. Also, I wonder what's the role of 別に here. I expect to see any negative word after 別に but I can't find any.

「我を忘れる」という表現がある。自分のことを忘れる、というのだから変な感じがするが、考えてみるとなかなかうまい表現だなと思う。映画などを見ていると、知らぬ間に主人公に同一化してしまって、主人公が苦境に立つと、こちらも胸が苦しくなったり、知らぬ間に手を握りしめていて、汗ばんできたりする。それは別に映画の話であって、自分はいすに座ってそれを見ているのだから、何のことはない、と言えばそれまでだが、そんな観客としての自分のことは忘れてしまっているのだ。

Is the last sentence is trying to say that there are some people might deny by saying that this situation is nothing special (because it is 映画の話) and that a viewer is watching a movie and nothing happens beside that (何のことはない), however it is caused by a viewer forgetting themself?

それ vaguely refers to in-movie scenes exemplified by 主人公が苦境に立つ. それは映画の話だ simply means "It's just a movie".
別に is usually used as a negative-polarity item meaning "(not) in particular". However, it's sometimes used somewhat like an interjection to indicate a lack of strong feeling/opinion/interest (i.e., 別に大した話ではない). Translating it as "well" or "I guess" is often enough, but it can sound like "meh" if used inappropriately.

How does 別に function as an adverb?
別に to mean "not particularly"

For example:

別に彼のことは好きですよ。
Well, I like him, I guess (although this is not a particularly strong feeling / this is not really an important topic).
別にいいですよ。
It's okay, I guess (I don't have any opinion about it).


Thank you. In your first example, I believe 私のこと is supposed to be 彼のこと.
